# How to align beamer slide content with markdown pandoc?

Tags: beamer, pandoc, markdown

I use markdown to generate beamer slides with pandoc.

This markdown...

```
# Test

foobar
```

...is compiled to this Latex:

```
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \protect\hypertarget{test}{}
  foobar
\end{frame}
```

What do I have to write in Markdown to align the content to the bottom, i.e. getting this output?

```
\begin{frame}[b]{Test}
  \protect\hypertarget{test}{}
  foobar
\end{frame}
```

P.S. I'm aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223786/pass-beamer-frame-options-arguments-in-pandoc?noredirect=1&lq=1) which asks for another case of marking a frame. Unfortunately it was wrongly closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give options in braces:

```
# Test {.b}

foobar
```

will result in

```
\begin{frame}[b]{Test}
\protect\hypertarget{test}{}
foobar
\end{frame}
```

Supported options are: `allowdisplaybreaks`, `allowframebreaks`, `b`, `c`, `t`, `environment`, `label`, `plain`, `shrink`, `standout`, `noframenumbering` (see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#frame-attributes-in-beamer)